# Zig Zag Line for HH LL , need to show distance in percent

Tags: pine-script

on tradingview I am using the script which ideally plot continue line between highs and lows , I wanted to implement percent of difference between highs and lows , I searched for many article but not able to find one , can someone please help me with this

```
//@version=4
study("Zig Zag Candle to Candle", overlay = true)
length = input(2, title = "High/Low length")
h = highest(high, length * 2 + 1)
l = lowest(low, length * 2 + 1)
f_isMin(len) => 
    l == low[len]
f_isMax(len) => 
    h == high[len]

var dirUp = false
var lastLow = high * 100
var lastHigh = 0.0
var timeLow = bar_index
var timeHigh = bar_index
var line li = na
f_drawLine() =>
    _li_color = dirUp ? color.teal : color.orange
    line.new(
         timeHigh - length, lastHigh, 
         timeLow - length, lastLow, 
         xloc.bar_index, color=_li_color, width=2
         )

if dirUp
    if (f_isMin(length) and low[length] < lastLow)
        lastLow := low[length]
        timeLow := bar_index
        line.delete(li)
        li := f_drawLine()


    if (f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastLow)
        lastHigh := high[length]
        timeHigh := bar_index
        dirUp := false
        li := f_drawLine()

if not dirUp
    if (f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastHigh)
        lastHigh := high[length]
        timeHigh := bar_index
        line.delete(li)
        li := f_drawLine()
    if f_isMin(length) and low[length] < lastHigh
        lastLow := low[length]
        timeLow := bar_index
        dirUp := true
        li := f_drawLine()
        if (f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastLow)
            lastHigh := high[length]
            timeHigh := bar_index
            dirUp := false
            li := f_drawLine()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable called `perCha`

```
perCha = thisHigh - lastHigh/lastHigh * 100  //You'll have to modify these variables to match the ones that you have declared in your script
```

Use this at the end of every if statement, so when the plot is done, this will also be triggered at the same time

`label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, text "Change from last value is" + tostring(perCha) + "%")`

Comment: Hi I had tried , but I am getting percChn in 1000 , where do I need to place this percha ?